# Timer, to start from zero and end at 10th second and after 10th second timer should become 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

```
if (coinMag == true) 
{

Timer += 1 * Time.deltaTime;

                if (Timer >= 10) 
                {

                   coinMag = false;
                    Timer = 0;
                }
            }
```

what I want is when the CoinMag is true the timer should start... I have intialized timer as public float `Timer=0.0f`; ..and after Timer starts exactly after 10 seconds Timer should be reinitialized to 0.

Comment: So whats wrong with this code?

Comment: If this should keep running "forever", `InvokeRepeating` or `Coroutine + WaitForSeconds` might be better for you than having something like the above in `Update`.

Comment: To keep it running though you would just need to leave out the `coinMag = false` and put that somewhere else (like an "external switch").

Comment: @Gunnar B .... now this timer is not working ...i want the timer to start from 0 and end at 10...can u suggest a method to that

Comment: Putting this code into `Update` should run it (you can leave out the `1 *` btw).

Comment: @nithin check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `coroutine`:

```
IEnumerator Timer(float duration,Action callBack = null)
{
    float elapsedTime = 0.0f;
    while (elapsedTime < duration)
    {
        yield return null;
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime ;
    }

    if (callBack != null)
    {
        callBack();
    }
}
```

as following:

```
StartCoroutine(Timer(10,()=>{Debug.Log("After 10 seconds");}));
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you need the timer values to be exposed (in addition to running a method when the timer expires), you can do this:

```
 private BackgroundWorker timer = new BackgroundWorker();
    public void initialize()
    {
        timer.DoWork += doTimer;
        timer.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    public double milliseconds_Remaining = 0;
    public double milliseconds_Transpired = 0;
    private void doTimer(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isRunning = true;
        DateTime begin = DateTime.Now;
        while (isRunning)
        {
            //update times
            double milliseconds = DateTime.Now.Subtract(begin).TotalMilliseconds;
            milliseconds_Remaining = 10000 - milliseconds;
            milliseconds_Transpired = milliseconds;
            if (milliseconds >= 10000)
            {

                //activate timer function

                //reset 
                begin = DateTime.Now;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);//or 500 or 50 depending on accuracy needed

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should definitely consider merging both of your answers into one, even if it means copying and pasting the content of one into the other.

Comment: Remember that this is Unity. You can achieve the result in a much easier way, your post is good for regular c# applications though.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge - I've deleted my other answer and will pay more attention to tags in the future. Cheers!